# Card flip animation Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to make a card flip and show its backside. It works in all other browsers but not in Internet Explorer 11.

I've tried adding -ms- prefaces, but that didn't help. The problem seems to be that IE does not support the css attribute `transform-style: preserve-3d`.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbkq94hr/

HTML

```
<body>
    <article>
        <div id="card0" class="card">
            <figure class="front">
            </figure>
            <figure class="back">
            </figure>
        </div>
    </article>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flipped = false;
    var card = $("#card0");
    card.click(function() { flipFunction();});

    function flipFunction() {
        if (flipped) {
            flipped = false;
            card.removeClass('flip');
        } else {
            card.addClass('flip');
            flipped = true;
        }
    };
});
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card {
    float:left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 139px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
    position: relative;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.back {
    background-color: blue;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: red;
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
}

article {
    height: 114px;
    width: 114px;
    perspective: 1000;
}
```

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments, I tried following David Walshes instructions, but still couldn't get it to work. https://jsfiddle.net/w9o2chmn/2/

Comment: Kindly refer https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip  it may help

Comment: That could work, but I couldn't get it to work on button click. :/

Comment: kindly check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I changed the jQuery code to perform card flip on click. Kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/w9o2chmn/6/

**HTML**
I added class `flip-container` to article tag

```
<article class="flip-container">
    <div id="card0" class="card">
        <figure class="front">
        front
        </figure>
        <figure class="back">
        back
        </figure>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**
I have removed the CSS `:hover` code and placed it in jQuery click

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  color:#fff;
}

/*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */
    /*.flip-container:hover .back {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .flip-container:hover .front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }*/

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.card {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background:red;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  background:blue;
}

/*
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flipped=false;

    $('.flip-container').on('click', function(){
        if(!flipped){
      $('.back').css('transform','rotateY(0deg)');
      $('.front').css('transform','rotateY(180deg)');
      flipped=true;
      console.log('true part :'+flipped);
      }
      else{
        $('.back').css('transform','rotateY(180deg)');
      $('.front').css('transform','rotateY(0deg)');
      flipped=false;
      console.log('else part :'+flipped);
      }
    });


});
```

Kindly let me know if its working for you...

**PS: I tested this on IE11 and its working for me**

Comment: The jsFiddle is not working for me in IE11. I'm on Windows 10

Comment: This is great and works for me in IE11, Opera, Firefox and Chrome but in Safari the animation looks strange.  It looks like half the card is red and half blue.  Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: doesn't work on ie11 on windows 10, only on windows 8

Comment: IE11 does not support animated 3d transforms. At least the 3d does not work anymore in Windows 10.

Comment: This worked great for me. To make the card flip look more natural, change the else .back transform from rotateY(180deg) to rotateY(-180deg).

Comment: is there any way to accomplish this without jquery? (using reactjs with react-app-polyfill/ie11)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the second animation is delaying so long as I have used this method in my own code exactly the same. Maybe someone can clean this up. 
Basically wanting to add a slight delay to change the z-index so it appears, as the animation is on it's edge (50% through animation), the z-index changes and allows it to have the correct card on top.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.flip-container').on('click', function(){
        if(!$(".front").hasClass("front_flip")) {
        
            $(".front").delay(200).queue(function(){
                $(this).addClass("flip_z_index").dequeue();
            });
            
            $('.front').addClass('front_flip');
            $('.back').removeClass('back_flip');
            
        } else {
        
            $(".front").delay(200).queue(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("flip_z_index").dequeue();
            });
            
            $('.front').removeClass('front_flip');
            $('.back').addClass('back_flip');
        
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    color:#fff;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.card {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front, .back {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 3;
    background:red;
}

.back {
    z-index:2;
    background:blue;
}

.front_flip {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.back_flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip_z_index {
    z-index:1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="flip-container">
    <div id="card0" class="card">
        <div class="front">
        front
        </div>
        <div class="back back_flip">
        back
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```